# Error CS0117: 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetTypeCode'

Tags: windows-store-apps

Can someone please help me learn how to read and navigate the msdn docs?

Is this not supported in .net 4.0+ ?

```
using System;

...

public static bool IsPositive( object Value, bool ZeroIsPositive )
{
    switch ( Type.GetTypeCode( Value.GetType() ) )
    {
        case TypeCode.SByte:
```

I'm finding it very difficult to find my way through the docs and know what applies to Windows Store Apps specifically...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Type.GetTypeCode()` is supported in full .NET apps and non-Store portable class libraries, but *not* in Windows Store apps.

If you look at the [`Type` class documentation in .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42892f65.aspx), you can see a green shopping bag next to all of the members which *are* supported in Windows Store apps.

You can also look at the bottom of the page for each individual member. For example, [`Type.GetArrayRank`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getarrayrank.aspx) has this:

> **Version Information**
>   **.NET Framework**
>   Supported in: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
>   **.NET Framework Client Profile**
>   Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1
>   **Portable Class Library**
>   Supported in: Portable Class Library
>   **.NET for Windows Store apps**
>   Supported in: Windows 8

... whereas [`Type.GetTypeCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypecode.aspx) has:

> **Version Information**
>   **.NET Framework**
>   Supported in: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
>   **.NET Framework Client Profile**
>   Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1
>   **Portable Class Library**
>   Supported in: Portable Class Library

(Note the lack of a mention of Windows Store.)

Comment: Any alternatives? I'm on a Xamarin PCL.

Comment: @Shimmy: Well what is the bigger goal here? And can you use netstandard instead of PCL now?

Comment: Not yet, I'm using Prism, which doesn't support netstandard yet... Trigger goal is primitive CLR types (string, decimal etc. should be included)

Comment: @Shimmy: Can you not just compare with `typeof(string)` etc?

Comment: That's what I'm gonna do.